# Using json2.js inside classic ASP

Tags: json, post, asp-classic, jscript

Good day,

I am confused as to when I am using VBScript, Javascript, and JScript inside classic ASP.
I've been told that our environment uses JScript by default.
So when we create a blank page with our company's standard includes, we just start coding in JScript.

Now I wish to use the json2.js file so that I can parse incoming JSON and send JSON out to clients/browsers.

I didn't think that I needed to do anything special to use json2.js since it's pure javascript. But I'm having issues placing the SCRIPT tag.  Basically when and where do I need a new SCRIPT tag inside a classic ASP page?

I am getting a 'JSON' is null or not an object' response.  That leads me to believe that the JSON.parse() method is not even being recognized.

Thanks

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server" src="json2.js"></script>

   <%
         .... ..... some ASP Code in JScript

    %>
    <script language="javascript" runat="server">

        var lngBytesCount
            lngBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes

        var requestBody = BytesToStr(Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount));
        //var jsonObject=JSON.parse(\"{"answer":"ok"}\");   

        var jsonObject=JSON.parse(requestBody); 

        Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        for (var i in jsonObject){
            Response.Write(jsonObject[i]);
        }

        //var json = eval(requestBody);
        //Response.Write(json);
        Response.End()

    </script>

    <%
     .... ..... some ASP Code in JScript
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to use the json2.js library client side or server-side.

Classic ASP is a server-side technology that supports different languages, the most popuplar being vbscript and jscript. This is the same as ASP.NET which can be written in C# or VB.

The code between `<%` and `%>` tags is executed server side. Also, blocks of code between `<script runat="server">` and `</script>` run server side.
If you leave out the `runat="server"` part, it runs client-side, and it is executed by the client browser.

So to answer your question, if you want to use it server-side; use `<script runat="server">`, if you want o use it client-side use `<script>`